# SQL Server - EBS Storage Design

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

We are planning our new EBS structure on amazon to get the best performance out of SQL Server. During the process some doubts appeared:

**1** - Using the Amazon calculator (http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) we got the costs below:

- General purpose (SSD)    - 1000GB - 3000 IOPS       =   **$184,30**
- Provisioned IOPS (SSD)   - 1000GB - 3000 IOPS       =   **$511,00**

This amount is a huge diference in a month for the same performance (???), I'm aware about the "IOPS burst implementation" on General purpose SSD, but according to documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html

When the volume size is 1000 GB the burst duration is "infinite" (Always 3000 IOPS).

Is it safe to say that the performance between the two disks above are exactly the same?

**2** - We need about 1700 GB for 100 databases, what layout should we use?

Options:

- Get two disks (GP SSD) with 1000GB (3000 IOPS) each and distribute the workload among this two.
- Get two disks (GP SSD) with 1000GB (3000 IOPS) each and put then together with RAID 0 ? (We will be able to have 6000 IOPS burst, but should I be worried about EBS fault?)
- Get four disks (GP SSD) with 1000GB (3000 IOPS) each and use RAID 10? (Is it necessary with EBS?)
- Give your suggestion, i will be glad to hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Amazon support, hope this helps!

---

Greetings

The disk cost question is easy enough to answer. General purpose (SSD) and Provisioned IOPS (SSD) use similar technology. Side by side they can achieve the same speeds, the only difference being that GP2 maximum sped is 3000 and PIOPs is 4000, per volume. One reason PIOPS is much more expensive is that you also pay for the number of IO you use, where as GP2 there is no per IO cost.

As for the design of the 1700GB datastore, there are 2 main factors. Redundancy and Performance. And of course cost is a big factor. To provide proper guidance here we would need to know what your actual needs are going to be then we could suggest some solutions. However, there are a couple of main RAID levels etc that match what you suggested that we can talk about.

- Get two disks (GP SSD) with 1000GB (3000 IOPS) each and distribute the workload among this two.
  No RAID. I take it you mean just have some databases on one volume and some on the other? This to me, is actually fine. All i would do in addition is backup the DBs to some other locally attached EBS volumes. This would be for workloads no greater that 3000 IO (read and writes combined). It's also easily expandable. Just add more disk.
- Get two disks (GP SSD) with 1000GB (3000 IOPS) each and put then together with RAID 0 ? (We will be able to have 6000 IOPS burst, but should I be worried about EBS fault?)
  RAID 0. All you have done here is make things twice as fast. But lose one disk and you lose everything. Again, if you are happy to restore from backup if a disk fails, this is a fast cheap config, for upto 6000 IO. Not easily expandable.
- Get four disks (GP SSD) with 1000GB (3000 IOPS) each and use RAID 10? (Is it necessary with EBS?)
  RAID 5, 6, and 10. These are all faster and more redundant. Arguably, RAID 10 is the best config for database, and probably the right config for you. With 1700 GB of data, if things go wrong there will be lots and lots of unhappy people.
- Any suggestions?
  Have you considered Amazon RDS? RDS has lots of advantages. We do all the heavy lifting, including multi AZ deployments, and RDS can expand vertically (CPU) and horizontally (Space) as your needs grow.

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/

The other thing to consider with GP2 is.... you 'might' not need to provision 1TB volumes. You probably do not need the 3000 IO 'infinity' burst model. Lets say you do want to run at 3000 IO all the time. Why not provision 5 x 200GB volumes, where each volume has 3 IO per GB. So 5x200x3=3000IO baseline. Put the 5 volumes in raid 5 (for example) and you should get around 3000IO all day long, and never run out of credit if you dont go over that (and IO is equally distributed)

However, those volumes can each burst to 3000 IO for 30 minutes continuous before you get rate limited to 600IO per vol. Which is still 3000IO in total. So... in this config you can burst to 15,000IO at anytime and when you do get limited you still have the 3000IO you predicted you need. Just don't run at over 3000 for more than needed or you'll have no burst left.

Neat huh? I think it is worthwhile to call or chat in to discuss your actual needs and answer any questions. Ultimately though, you will need to test and benchmark which ever design you decide to go with as talking about things and actual results will always differ! I imagine you guys are quite advanced but - here is a great example benchmark if you want to do some simple tests on various designs to help you decide what is best.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/benchmark_piops.html